# A complete guide to deploy django with nginx and uwsgi (which works)?

Tags: django, nginx, installation, uwsgi

This is a fairly new combination, but if you want to avoid Apache, seems to be the most stable solution with the least RAM footprint. So I am desperately looking to implement it. The official uwsgi doc is too brief to be useful for a non-geeky user. Of course there are few guides (like [this](http://django.docshub.org/tutorials/4/deploying-your-applications-with-nginx-and-uwsgi), and [this](http://senya.pl/2011/03/sexy-nginx-uwsgi-stack-for-django-with-virtualenv/)) which appear to be complete. However, I have tried them (along with a couple of other guides) with no success.

So please share a guide to install django+nginx+uwsgi on Linux, which does not assume any hidden steps and you have actually have tried and succeed.

Comment: What kind of failure you ran into following the guides you linked?

Comment: Yes, why not just tell the problems you're experiencing, so people can help you there? I don't think you're going to find anyone that's going to sit down and write a complete guide here just for you.

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131459/deploying-flask-on-cherokee-and-uwsgi/5131673#5131673) to another question involving uWSGI might be of use to you, though it's for Cherokee, not nginx (and flask, but that shouldn't matter since flask and Django are both WSGI compliant).